# reloading div doesn't update time if it's called from another function

Tags: javascript, html, nwjs

I have a time function

```
function hm()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var h = ('0'+d.getHours()).substr(-2);
    var m = ('0'+d.getMinutes()).substr(-2);
    var str0 =  h + ':' + m;

  return {date: str0, hour: h, minute: m};


}



var hm = hm();
var date = hm.date;
var hour = hm.hour;
var minute = hm.minute;
```

and I have a div

```
<div id="mytime">Time</div>
```

I call time function from this which updates the div

```
function refreshDiv() {


document.getElementById('mytimer').innerHTML =  'Time:.....' + hm.date;

}


$(document).ready(function () {
   setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000); 
});
```

It won't update the time like `12:03` `12:04` but if I place `function hm()` and variables `var hm = hm(); var date = hm.date;` into `function refreshDiv()` block it works.

How can I make it work?

EDIT: 
This is a nwjs project.

If I add `hm = hm();` inside `refreshDiv()` I get:

```
 "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function", source: file:///home/.../index.html (182)
```

182 is line number of included `hm = hm();`

Comment: Just add `hm = hm();` inside `refreshDiv()` because now it is called only once.

Comment: Don't use a variable with the same name as the function. You're removing the function definition when you do that. Try `var thisHm = hm();`\

Comment: @Barmar hey you saved my day. `var thisHm = hm();` worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to store individual values:

```
var hm = hm();
var date = hm.date;
var hour = hm.hour;
var minute = hm.minute;
```

You have a function `hm()`: call it, and immediately get the value of a returned object:

```
document.getElementById('mytimer').innerHTML = 'Time: ' + hm().date;
```

Why? Let's use Chrome DevTools to clarify this.

[image]

So, you defined a function `hm()`.
When you call it, you get the returned object: `{a: 0000000000000, b: "test"}`
You can access the *fields* of this object with `.`

```
var object = hm(); // Assign the returned value of hm() to object
alert(object.a);   // Alerts value of the field a of object
```

If you don't want to allocate new variables, use `hm().a`. You will conserve memory and time.

Comment: I get `undefined` output.

Comment: I found the bug. As Barmar pointed out using different variable than function name fixed it.

Comment: @kenn Why use variables? You can get hm().data just fine

Comment: @http://stackoverflow.com/users/7401478/weary-adventurer you are right, I just tried it and it works well. I am just a beginner. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: @kenn No problem! To notify a person, mention their name like `@WearyAdventurer`. If my solution solved your problem, you might want to upvote and mark this answer as accepted.